# Spark MySql connector Jar

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc

I am connecting to a MySql DB from a spark application(spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7). While connecting, I am getting below error.

Here is my code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("LoadMySql")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")

    val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .config(conf)
    .getOrCreate()

    val option = Map("url" -> "jdbc://mysql://IPAddress:3306/TestDB", "dbtable" -> "Users", "user" -> "root", "password" -> "*****")

    val dataRDD = spark.sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc").options(option).load()
```

Error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(JdbcUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
    at com.Lab.SparkAPI.LoadMySql$.main(LoadMySql.scala:26)
    at com.Lab.SparkAPI.LoadMySql.main(LoadMySql.scala)
```

I have already included mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar into my eclipse project via Add External Jars.

I tried couple different version of jar but no luck so far.

Any idea which version do I need connect to MySQL?

---

[edit]

Finally I am able to connect & load data from MySQL...

I did below 2 settings...

- GRANT ALL ON DBName.* TO "root"@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
- modify /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf to comment #bind-address = 127.0.0.1 under [mysqld] section

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517798/jdbc-connection-to-mysql-from-a-remote-machine/52523274#52523274)

Comment: Could you try loading the MySql  driver class, exactly before where you call DriverManager.getConnection

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Scala as programming language. You are not providing enough information, such us the code you are using to connect to MySQL. Anyways, it looks like you have not specified any driver for MySQL. Try it:

1. Import the MySQL to your proyect

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>5.1.39</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create the `Properties` object, specifying the jdbc driver. Then, use this object to write/read to/from MySQL.

   ```scala
   val prop = new Properties()

   prop.setProperty("user", dbUser)
   prop.setProperty("password", dbPassword)
   prop.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

   df.write.mode("append").jdbc("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + "/" + dbName + "?rewriteBatchedStatements=true", "TABLE_NAME", prop)
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't post here such a long code sample in a comment. It would be better if you update your question :) Anyway, did my approach work for you?

Comment: I have included jar file into my project, is it not enough? Or do I need to import it the way you mentioned.

Comment: Importing manually libraries in a Scala project is not a good practice, it's better to use tools like Maven or SBT for that purpose. Anyways, make sure that the library has been properly imported to the project.