# JDBC connection to MySql from a remote machine

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc

I have installed MySql in a Linux VM (in a windows desktop), I am trying to connect to MySql from a Spark application running in a parent windows OS. While connecting I am getting below error...

Here is the sample code

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("LoadMySql")
.setMaster("local[*]")
.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")

val spark = SparkSession
.builder
.config(conf)
.getOrCreate()

val option = Map("url" -> "jdbc:mysql://VMIP:3306/TestDB", "dbtable" -> "Users", "user" -> "root", "password" -> "*****", "driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

val dataRDD = spark.sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc").options(option).load()
```

}

Error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
at com.Lab.SparkAPI.LoadMySql$.main(LoadMySql.scala:29)
at com.Lab.SparkAPI.LoadMySql.main(LoadMySql.scala)
```

I already changed bind-address property in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf.
I have tried few options for bind-address - linux VM IP, 0.0.0.0 and completely commenting it.

None of the options worked so far.

My guess is, my windows application is not able to access MySql which is running in a VM.

Can somebody help me in resolving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem related to connecting (otherwise I'd expect a SQLException of that nature).

Comment: This might be due to firewall blocking connection to MySql.

Comment: Not likely, as that would result in a SQLException (eg a communications link failure).

Comment: I even can't connect using MySQL client from windows desktop, I am getting Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at MyIP:3306: Host 'MyIP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if host machine can connect to mysql in VM or not via mysql client.
2. These are the Options which can be applied in `val option = Map()`:::
   https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCOptions.scala

> ```
>   val JDBC_URL = newOption("url")
>   val JDBC_TABLE_NAME = newOption("dbtable")
>   val JDBC_QUERY_STRING = newOption("query")
>   val JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS = newOption("driver")
>   val JDBC_PARTITION_COLUMN = newOption("partitionColumn")
>   val JDBC_LOWER_BOUND = newOption("lowerBound")
>   val JDBC_UPPER_BOUND = newOption("upperBound")
>   val JDBC_NUM_PARTITIONS = newOption("numPartitions")
>   val JDBC_QUERY_TIMEOUT = newOption("queryTimeout")
>   val JDBC_BATCH_FETCH_SIZE = newOption("fetchsize")
>   val JDBC_TRUNCATE = newOption("truncate")
>   val JDBC_CASCADE_TRUNCATE = newOption("cascadeTruncate")
>   val JDBC_CREATE_TABLE_OPTIONS = newOption("createTableOptions")
>   val JDBC_CREATE_TABLE_COLUMN_TYPES = newOption("createTableColumnTypes")
>   val JDBC_CUSTOM_DATAFRAME_COLUMN_TYPES = newOption("customSchema")
>   val JDBC_BATCH_INSERT_SIZE = newOption("batchsize")
>   val JDBC_TXN_ISOLATION_LEVEL = newOption("isolationLevel")
>   val JDBC_SESSION_INIT_STATEMENT = newOption("sessionInitStatement")
>   val JDBC_PUSHDOWN_PREDICATE = newOption("pushDownPredicate")
> ```

Comment: While connecting from MySQL workbench, I am getting below error...

Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at MyIP:3306: Host 'MyIP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to connect MySQL remotely...

I did below 2 settings...

- GRANT ALL ON DBName.* TO "root"@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
- modify /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf to comment #bind-address = 127.0.0.1 under [mysqld] section

This question was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435554/remotely-access-mysql-db-on-vm-from-windows-as-host)